# What is the Protractor way to test what is shown before Angular loads

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

I believe that it's a good practice to inform users that an Angular-based application is loading. I mean, in case of Angular 2, it's e.g. `<view>Loading...</view>`. I am sure that there is a way to do the same in AngularJS (v1) as well. Thus I believe that there should be a way to use Protractor to test such aspect of the application since it [is](http://angular.github.io/protractor/) "an end-to-end test framework for AngularJS applications".

It was [suggested](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2705#issuecomment-156878334) to me that there is a way to do that and that I should ask here. So, can you please help me to find the approach which had [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048479/nick-tomlin) on his mind? It does no necessarily has to be compatible with Angular 2 already. AngularJS (v1) approach would be enough since I believe that it will be ported once they port Protractor.

This question seems to be similar to [Protractor: test loading state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32119444/5566882) but unlike OP I want to make sure that the Angular application is not loaded before the test finishes so I guess that there should be a way to suspend/stop loading of the application (but I may be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I typically avoid testing things like this because they tend to be very flakey. Unless there's some requirement to test the loader I would not do so.

You can use `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` to *not* wait for angular to load on the page, and then assert that your loader is there.

The only issue with this is that you will struggle with ensuring that angular has not loaded. There's no great way of preventing your angular application from bootstrapping unless you manually bootstrap and build in some sort of delay or "no-bootstrap" trigger but that starts compromising your application just to test a loading state.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Nick's point, you would definitely need to *turn the synchronization between protractor and angular off* and set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;`.

Then, you can/should add an [explicit wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) to wait for the loading indicator (for instance, it may be a spinner image) to [become visible](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.visibilityOf):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("#loading"))), 5000, "Loading indicator has not become visible");
```

A timeout error would mean that the loading element (in this case the element with `id="loading"`) has not become visible in 5 seconds.

Don't forget to turn the sync back on after the test is completed:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```